# android firebase messaging. check device group created?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I want to send messages from one user's device to other user's devices (could be multiple). As far as I understand from the docs, it can be done using firebase device group messaging, where a device group will contain all user's devices.

For this I have to create and manage groups from android devices. However, I haven't found the info on how to create a group or check if the group exists from android device.

Please help.

Comment: See [Managing device groups on Android client apps](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/device-group#managing-device-groups-on-android-client-apps) in the Firebase documentation.

Comment: Frank, that's exactly what i read and it doesn't say how to create a group or check if a group exists from device

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that device groups are managed by your app server, not on the client. It is the app server (as Frank points out) that manages which tokens are part of which groups. Device groups are designed to enable syncing of state between a group of devices, more specifically a single user's group of devices. It is not really intended to be used for device to device messaging. It is a way to broadcast a message to all devices in the group.

Since you would need to implement a server anyway to maintain the device groups then you should use the server as a relay between messages from one device to another.